# Kafka KSQL Re partition and rekey problem

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have defined a stream

```
CREATE STREAM QUOTE (quoteId VARCHAR,
                      counterPartyId VARCHAR)
        WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='quotes',
              VALUE_FORMAT='JSON',
              KEY='quoteId');
```

I want to aggregate how many quotes I got so far , and the last quoteId on that event

```
CREATE TABLE KQUOTE AS
    SELECT Max(CAST(quoteId as INT)) as quoteId,COUNT(*) AS COUNT
        FROM QUOTE
        GROUP BY 1;
```

Turn this Table to Stream cause I want to know the aggregation result history. (Seem like I have to use underlying topic to create stream. Can't directly create stream from table 'KQUOTE').

```
CREATE stream KQuoteStream (quoteId VARCHAR,
                      count INT)
        WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='KQUOTE',
              VALUE_FORMAT='JSON',
              KEY='quoteId');
```

I expect above use RAWKEY quoteId, but it's not. As we can see below the RAWKEY is always 1(since we group by constant 1 when creating table kquote).

```
ksql> select * from KQuoteStream;
1574121797111 | 1 | 806 | 20
1574121979291 | 1 | 807 | 21
```

Try to re partition the stream by quoteId to change RAWKEY to be quoteId

```
CREATE stream KQuoteStreamByQuoteId
        as
    SELECT quoteId, COUNT FROM KQuoteStream PARTITION BY quoteId;
```

RAMKEY is still constant 1

```
ksql> select * from KQuoteStreamByQuoteId;
1574121797111 | 1 | 806 | 20
1574121979291 | 1 | 807 | 21
```

BTW: All topic has same partition as 1 to make things simpler. 
Anyone has some idea? Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

That's definitely an interesting bug you've surfaced!

The trick here is to understand that the `WITH(KEY='quoteId')` doesn't actually *do* anything, it's a hint to ksqlDB that the key field happens to also exist in the value as `quoteId`. Then, when you `PARTITION BY quoteId`, it thinks that you are partitioning by the rowkey so it does nothing! I agree that this behavior is pretty unintuitive, which is why we are planning to remove `WITH(KEY=...)` functionality in favor of something more intuitive (to be determined).

In the meantime, the workaround should be to *not* specify the key when you create `KQuoteStream` so that KSQL doesn't optimize away the repartition.